# Workaround for my hosting provider blocking all ports except for 80?

Tags: php, html, xml, proxy, port

I need to access an XML for my website (to give information to my listeners) the link looks like this: http://???.???.130.139:9465/stats
That ip + port is for my radio stream and cannot be changed.

As you can see it has to have :9465 (port 9465) in the url and therefore I cannot connect to it as all ports are blocked except the main few. (http, ftp etc..)

Is there any way I can still access it without switching hosting providers?

The XML outputs something like this:

```
<SHOUTCASTSERVER>
    <CURRENTLISTENERS>44</CURRENTLISTENERS>
    <PEAKLISTENERS>131</PEAKLISTENERS>
    <MAXLISTENERS>10000</MAXLISTENERS>
    <UNIQUELISTENERS>42</UNIQUELISTENERS>
    <AVERAGETIME>4519</AVERAGETIME>
    <SERVERGENRE>Hip Hop</SERVERGENRE>
    <SERVERGENRE2/>
    <SERVERGENRE3/>
    <SERVERGENRE4/>
    <SERVERGENRE5/>
    <SERVERURL>http://www.?????????.net</SERVERURL>
    <SERVERTITLE>????? Radio</SERVERTITLE>
    <SONGTITLE>DJ Mitsu The Beats - All Work Out</SONGTITLE>
    <SONGURL>?????????.net</SONGURL>
    <STREAMHITS>22</STREAMHITS>
    <STREAMSTATUS>1</STREAMSTATUS>
    <BACKUPSTATUS>0</BACKUPSTATUS>
    <STREAMLISTED>1</STREAMLISTED>
    <STREAMSOURCE>???.???.128.60</STREAMSOURCE>
    <STREAMPATH>/stream</STREAMPATH>
    <STREAMUPTIME>1</STREAMUPTIME>
    <BITRATE>128</BITRATE>
    <CONTENT>audio/mpeg</CONTENT>
    <VERSION>2.4.7.256 (posix(linux x64))</VERSION>
</SHOUTCASTSERVER>
```

Comment: You mean your hosting provider is blocking __outgoing__ traffic that is not in common ports?

Comment: You will need to move to another provider. An idea could be a tunnel, but moving your web should be easier and cheaper. Since there is no programming solution, SO is the wrong place for that question. You would get better answers on a partner site, see pulldown menu on the top/left.

Comment: They have blocked/closed both incoming & outgoing @vesperto

Comment: They likely have bocked all outgoing traffic, even port 80. That's common practice in the webhost business.

Comment: Then you have to change provider (or convince them to open outgoing traffic).